# Characters being rendered strangely in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I'm presenting an RSS feed with this part of a `PHP` function:

```
echo "<li><a target='_blank' href='$item_link'>$item_title</a></li>";
```

Using an example, this output the following in `HTML`:

```
<li>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://www.internationalaccountingbulletin.com/news/ey-shinnihon-will-audit-toshibas-corrected-accounts-while-under-investigation-4639900'>
        EY ShinNihon will audit Toshibaâ€™s corrected accountsâ€¦ while under investigation
    </a>
</li>
```

The titles have a large amount of discrepancy when it comes to the symbols used.

It outputs this

> EY ShinNihon will audit Toshiba’s corrected accounts… while under investigation

as

> EY ShinNihon will audit Toshibaâ€™s corrected accountsâ€¦ while under investigation

with apostrophes and ellipses (among others) being various symbols prefixed by `â€`.

How can I convert these symbols back to the originals in `PHP`?

Comment: You need to **handle encodings correctly**, as simple and hard as that. You'll have to show what exactly you're doing for anyone to be able to help you. Start here to help yourself: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-encodings

Comment: I took out the charset meta tag because I understood that it was bad practice for speed/SEO. When putting it back in, the problem is rectified, thank you. However, is there an alternative that is better practice? Setting headers via PHP - is that prefferable or worse?

Answer (score 1):

Choose you character encoding to match your what you are editing check this site to learn more. http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Answer (score 1):

> I took out the charset meta tag because I understood that it was bad practice for speed/SEO. When putting it back in, the problem is rectified, thank you. However, is there an alternative that is better practice? Setting headers via PHP - is that prefferable or worse?

So your problem was that you were outputting text in some encoding, without informing the browser what encoding you're giving it, and the browser therefore misinterpreting the text in the wrong encoding, leading to garbage characters. You always need to inform clients about what encoding you're sending them text in. **The primary method** to do that over HTTP is an HTTP `Content-Type` header. That way the browser is informed about the type of content it receives before it actually receives the content. Which is exactly as it should be.

HTML `<meta>` tags are only a **fallback**. You *should* include them, since they help specify the encoding of the HTML document should it ever be used outside of an HTTP context (e.g. you just open it from your hard disk, no HTTP involved, no HTTP `Content-Type` header, no way to specify the encoding... other than the HTML `<meta>` tag). But again, it should only be a fallback. And there's absolutely no issue with SEO or speed; wherever you got that from, it's pure FUD.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.
first just use mb_convert_encoding() function it will wok for you.

```
 $item_title = addslashes('this is your text');

 $item_title = mb_convert_encoding($item_title, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8');
```